# Huge xml Collada file. Use dom on it, how?

Tags: xml, dom, collada, sketchup

We got a huge assignment (don't worry, the deadline passed last week so this ain't for cheating) and now I'm trying to figure out what this file is about.

I got no information about the file, just the code in an email and my task was to represent the data in a "good way". I chose to use DOM for this. 
The thing is, I don't really know what this file is about. 
1. What do you use it for?
2. why and how do you use it?
3. What kind of data in this thing would be interesting to show on a webpage?

Sorry for a relly vauge "question", don't really know what to ask for.
Any information about this file is interesting to me, just want to understand it!

Lastly:
[Link to the XML-document/structure tree](http://wwwlab.iit.his.se/a15cecal/php/huvuduppgift.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a COLLADA file and contains 3D content. Actually, it is not really that huge for a 3D content, I have seen some examples over 100 Mb. That's how it looks like in Sketchup:

[image: Your content]

There are some image files missing, which are needed to display the textures. But they were not on the link, so texturing was not successful.
You can try to parse the file with DOM and display it yourself, which is not possibly the fastest way. Or you can use some existing API for your web page like `three.js`, which I would recommend to do. You don't really want to deal with the intern structure of COLLADA.

Comment: We could only choose between DOM,  XSLT and so on, it was a big assignment to test if we got the hang of it. I sorta think this file was unfair since there's not really a way for me to display it's content in a good way?

Comment: @Cset You need a viewer. DOM is not a viewer, you can parse the file with it, but you still need a graphical interface to show it.

Comment: Ah that is quite nice to hear! Since we only could use one of them (the course was only about this). Was quite afraid that there was a way to show it with DOM that I just didn't understand. But it seem I did everything right if that's the case! :)

Comment: Quick question though, if you had to display the data in this file with only DOM, what data would you put in, say a table?

Comment: A tree would be the best display option, as it has a hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0):

The file contains a link to a schema, which in turn contains a link to a specification at http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_4.pdf The specification answers your questions.

Comment: Is it even possible to display the data in a good way? I can only use DOM and it seems like I can only get the information about textures, cameras and so on,and not actually show them in a graphical way?

Comment: Since there is a specification of what the data means, it is presumably possible to write an application that displays the data in an attractive way. But it might require months of effort: I don't know without studying the specification. Some XML files (the files for Microsoft Word are an example) are so complex that extracting the information is a major undertaking.